# clickhouse table creation error in ubuntu

Tags: sql, clickhouse, sqlyog, clickhouse-client

I installed the clickhouse program in the ubuntu operating system and connected the SQLyog program. I can create a database, but I cannot create a table in it. It gives the following CODE:119 error.

ubuntu :) create table taxonomy_object_firewalls

CREATE TABLE taxonomy_object_firewalls

Query id: 37520dd5-44b9-436f-a5b6-96002f0a4ce7

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.

Received exception from server (version 22.2.2):
Code: 119. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Table engine is not specified in CREATE query. (ENGINE_REQUIRED)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting that Rich's syntax had a small unnecessary () after the ENGINE definition but was still successfully created in my testing. This syntax would be more accurate to the documentation:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS helloworld;

CREATE TABLE helloworld.my_first_table
(
    user_id UInt32,
    message String,
    timestamp DateTime,
    metric Float32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ["Getting Started" guide](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start#step-3-create-a-database-and-table) in the docs. ClickHouse is unique in that every table has an `Engine`. Table engines determine where and how the data is stored. When in doubt, use `MergeTree`:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS helloworld;

CREATE TABLE helloworld.my_first_table
(
    user_id UInt32,
    message String,
    timestamp DateTime,
    metric Float32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, timestamp)
```

Also, make sure you read about the primary key and how it works in ClickHouse. Primary keys are not typically unique, but instead determine the sort order.

Comment: I copied the example in the link you sent and created a table, but I still get an error. I cannot create a table.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: now i also tried to add a different table and i am facing this issue

Comment: Code: 50. DB::Exception: Received from 127.0.0.1:9000. DB::Exception: Unknown data type family: StringL. Maybe you meant: ['String','SINGLE']. (UNKNOWN_TYPE)

Comment: StringL is not a data type - probably just a typo. Use String.

Comment: I'll look into it and reply back thanks.