# cubejs clickhouse external db table engine not specified

Tags: cube, olap-cube

I am trying to use cubejs with mysql as the internal db and clickhouse as the external pre-aggregation database. But every time the scheduler is trying to build the external table, it is throwing `Unknown error field: Code: 119. DB::Exception: Table engine is not specified in CREATE query. (ENGINE_REQUIRED) (version 22.7.2.1)`. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500385/clickhouse-table-creation-error-in-ubuntu) and found that `ENGINE = MergeTree()` will solve this. grepping the clubejs packages I found the mergetree to be present inside the [ClickHouseQuery.js](https://github.com/cube-js/cube/blob/15e51bcb19ce22c38b71f4685484295fc637e44c/packages/cubejs-schema-compiler/src/adapter/ClickHouseQuery.js#L237), However it seems like that package even though present in the node_modules is not getting used while running the pre-aggregation query. The following is the error stack:-

[image]

[image]

and the `.env` looks like this:-

```
CUBEJS_DB_TYPE=mysql
CUBEJS_DB_HOST=host
CUBEJS_DB_USER=user
CUBEJS_DB_PASS=password
CUBEJS_DB_NAME=primary_db

CUBEJS_EXT_DB_TYPE=clickhouse
CUBEJS_EXT_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
CUBEJS_EXT_DB_PORT=8123
CUBEJS_EXT_DB_USER=default

CUBEJS_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT=true
CUBEJS_SCHEDULED_REFRESH_DEFAULT=true
CUBEJS_DEV_MODE=true
CUBEJS_SCHEMA_PATH=model
```

am I missing out on any other configs ?

Answer (score 0):

Storing pre-aggregations in Clickhouse is unsupported by the latest versions of Cube. Cube Store is the only supported option.

Comment: which version of cube supports clickhouse ?